# How to update dataset from listbox

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I am trying to make a simple asset management system for my work place.

I want users to have the ability to check multiple assets out to themselves.

To do this they would type the SM number of the asset/s they want into a textbox, click a button and this would then transfer the numbers to a listbox.

Then when they have added all the SM numbers they require, they can then check them out by clicking another button.

How do I search for and update the dataset to do this. 
Here is what I have so far, but I am stuck on the query.

I want to search for the `SM` number, and if the `SM column` of a row contains the `SM` number, i then want to update the `CheckedOut` column to `true` and the `CheckedOutTo` column to `logged in user`

[image]

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (var row in listBox1.Items)
        {
            if(sIMSDataSet.Stock.Rows.Contains(row))
            {
                //update the checked out column to true and the who it 
                //is checked out to, to the logged in user. 

            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to update it, or if what I am doing is efficient.

Comment: How does your `DataSet` look like? What does your question has to do with `sql`?

Comment: My `dataset` is a SQL database behind.

Comment: Then please show the table structure and the SQL statements you tried

Comment: i have updated the question, i havnt tried and sql statements becuase i have never worked with the data in this way, i have always worked from the datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it our myself:

```
 //Check checkin/out state and set to opiset
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[5].Value.Equals(true))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[5].Value = false;
                newHistoryRow["Action"] = "Checkout";
                sIMSDataSet.Tables["History"].Rows.Add(newHistoryRow);
                historyTableAdapter.Update(sIMSDataSet);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[5].Value = true;
                newHistoryRow["Action"] = "Checkin";
                sIMSDataSet.Tables["History"].Rows.Add(newHistoryRow);
                historyTableAdapter.Update(sIMSDataSet);
            }
            //check if username cell is empty, if is empty add username if is full remove username
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[4].Value as string))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[4].Value = username;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[numberRow].Cells[4].Value = "";
            }
```